# Get name of day from timestamp in Android

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp, deprecated

I have a class that when its initialized, it records the time of initialization in a private field with a public getter:

```
public class TestClass {

   private long mTimestamp;

    public TestClass(){
      mTimestamp = System.getCurrentMillis();
    }

    public long getTimestamp(){
          return mTimestamp;
    }
}
```

I also have an enum with the name of days:

```
public enum Days implements Serializable {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY
}
```

Now the problem is in another class I have to get the timestamp and set a `Days` field to the day that the class was initialized:

```
public class OtherClass {

     public Days getDayOfInitialization(TestClass testClass){
          //how to do this?
          Date date = new Date(testClass.getTimestamp())
          Days day = Date.getDay(); //Deprecated!
          //convert to enum and return...
     }
}
```

The `getDay()` method of `Date` is deprecated...how should I do this?

Comment: Day in which time zone? It's Wednesday for me right now, but in Australia it's already Thursday... (You probably want to use `Calendar` - or better yet, Joda Time...)

Comment: Why don't you just use [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)?

Comment: @TylerOlson I couldnt find how to initialize calendar with a perviously known timestamp!

Comment: @JonSkeet yes master!

Comment: @Sean87: Look at `Calendar.setTimeInMillis`. But you still need to think about time zones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Standard Week

You do not need that Enum as the standard for date-time ([ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) defines a week as Monday to Sunday.

Joda-Time defines constants for each day-of-week name in English such as [DateTimeConstants.MONDAY](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#MONDAY).

## Avoid java.util.Date

You should be using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) library, as the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Joda-Time works in Android according to others.

## Avoid Milliseconds As Date-Time

Tracking date-time as milliseconds is less than optimal. Serializing to a ISO 8601 string is preferable. But if you must, so be it.

## Time Zone Is Crucial

Time zone is crucial. Day-of-week is defined by time zone, as the comments above discussed.

If you want [UTC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), Joda-Time provides the constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

## Joda-Time

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( millisSinceEpochInUtc, timeZone );
int dayOfWeekNumber = dateTime.getDayOfWeek(); // ISO 8601 standard says Monday is 1.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEEE" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH );
String dayOfWeekName = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Answer (score 11):

If you just need the current day of week in a human-readable format, formatted to the current user's locale, then you could use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String dayString = sdf.format(new Date());
```

If their locale is "en_US", the output is:

```
Wednesday
```

If their locale is "de_DE", the output is:

```
Mittwoch
```

If their locale is "fr_FR", the output is:

```
mercredi
```

But if you need a numerical representation of the day of week (for example, you wanted to get '1' if it is Sunday or '2' if it is Monday), then you could use Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayInt = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 3):

use `Calendar`:

```
  long timeStamp = testClass.getTimestamp();
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);

  int dayNum = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

  Days day = Days.values()[dayNum];

  return day;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Calendar.getInstance()` method, which provide a calendar based on System Settings' TimeZone

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then get the day of the week as an int (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, and so on...)

```
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```