# How to convert a string which is received in unix format 1432191600 to only day?

Tags: android

I am getting this json data in the form of a date in unix timestamp , and i want to show it as only day names in listview , is it possible to achieve it ?

```
list: [
        {
         dt: 1432191600,
         temp: {
         day: 33.53,
         min: 25.92,
         }
        }
     ]
```

and i have converted it to like 21-05-2015 , but i want to just show the day names for the whole week.

```
String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
long dt = Long.parseLong(date);
Date date = new Date(dt * 1000L);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Can anybody give any suggestion ?
Thank You

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540443/get-name-of-day-from-timestamp-in-android

Comment: you mean you need to display Monday, Tuesday .... etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Date(long miliseconds) constructor overload to create a date instance.

> Initializes this Date instance using the specified millisecond value. The value is the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT.

source: [Date class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date(long))

then pass it to a calendar constructor and use the DAY_OF_WEEK property to retreive the day as integer.

```
Date myDate = new Date(yourLinuxTimestamp);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

i'm sure there is a better solution without haveing to create a Date instance .. just check the [Calendar Class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for replying but i got what i wanted

Instead of:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

I changed it to:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
```

which returns Thursday , Friday , Saturday , Monday , Tuesday

@Maroun Maroun `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E");` is also right which returns Thu , Fri , Sat , Mon , Tue

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code:

```
   String m_date="1432191600";
   SimpleDateFormat myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String m_parsed = myDate.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(m_date) * 1000L));
    System.out.println("Date:====== " + m_parsed); 
    try {
        Date m_day = myDate.parse(m_parsed);

        CharSequence m_daysGet = DateFormat.format("EEEE", m_day.getTime());
        System.err.println("Days are=============" + m_daysGet);
} catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```